# How can I make a responsive padding that takes up as much space as possible without touching other elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive, padding

I'm working on my website's footer, but I've come across a small design problem. I have a "footer__socials" div, and it contains multiple "footer__link"s, small icons that link to the socials. I'm trying to get a tab effect by having each links padding extend so they all have equal horizontal padding that goes out until it hits another socials padding. I've come across the problem of not being able to find any way I can make the padding for all the links take up as much space as possible whilst being equally sized. Here's what my page and code looks like:

My webpage. As I've poorly annotated, My mouse is hovering over one of the icons, which has a nice light background that matches with the upper footer whilst contrasting with the socials area. I want it to be so that the padding for all these icons adjusts responsively so that the light areas on hover are all equal and as big as possible, giving you a nice, clean tab-switching effect when you hover over a different icon

[image]

My code for the footer links and the text above them(unrelated). I have set the padding for 0 0 for now(it's the second 0, the horizontal padding, i need to fix) because I've been experimenting to try and find a solution and I'm currently using 0 as a placeholder for it.

```
.footer__socials {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #2d2d2d;
}

.footer__link {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #9f9f9f;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    padding: 0 0;
    transition: 0.15s;
}

.footer__link:hover {
    background: #333333;
}
```

I tried seeing if I could use the "space-between" option for it, although as I expected, it had no effect(I think this is because the setting doesn't even work with padding). I think I might be able to use a "calc()" function to get the space between the element next to it and half it to get the padding needed, but I don't know what variables and such I need to use for that equation ):

Here's the HTML as requested by @ADyson:

```
<footer class="footer">    
            <div class="footer__text container">
                <p class="footer__text--tp">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum perferendis accusantium nostrum unde sunt vero. Sit ratione id, reprehenderit assumenda corrupti deserunt harum praesentium officiis mollitia, tenetur veritatis, quae labore.</p>
                <p>Copyright Rubix Games LLC - &copy;2021-2022</p>
                <hr class="footer__hr">
                <div class="footer__socials">
                    <a href="https://youtube.com/@KingedKimed" class="footer__link" target="_blank"><i class="mdi mdi-youtube"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/KingedKimed" class="footer__link" target="_blank"><i class="mdi mdi-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://patreon.com/KingedKimed" class="footer__link" target="_blank"><i class="mdi mdi-patreon"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://store.steampowered.com" class="footer__link" target="_blank"><i class="mdi mdi-steam"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://youtube.com" class="footer__link" target="_blank"><i class="mdi mdi-youtube"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>       
        </footer>
```

Comment: As per [ask], please upload all code as _text_, not pictures. We can't re-use pictures of code in answers etc.

Comment: Also, CSS without HTML is unlikely to form a [mre] of the issue, which we'd need in order to fix it. We need suffficient code to be able to see the problem. CSS without HTML is pretty much meaningless, as we can't tell what effect it would have without seeing the HTML it's applied to. Also, this clearly has nothing to do with PHP, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the `justify-content` property to `center` for the `footer__socials` class and set the padding to a variable 5% for the `footer__link`s so that it would still have all the links stacked next to each other and get the tab effect I was looking for.